# Apply function to every value in an R dataframe

Tags: r

I have a 58 column dataframe, I need to apply the transformation $log(x_{i,j}+1)$ to all values in the first 56 columns. What method could I use to go about this most efficiently? I'm assuming there is something that would allow me to do this rather than just using some for loops to run through the entire dataframe.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should be able to just refer to the columns you want, and do the operation, ie:

```
df[,1:56] <- log(df[,1:56]+1)
```

Answer (score 37):

alexwhan's answer is right for log (and should probably be selected as the correct answer).  However, it works so cleanly because log is vectorized.  I have experienced the special pain of non-vectorized functions too frequently.  When I started with R, and didn't understand the apply family well, I resorted to ugly loops very often.  So, for the purposes of those who might stumble onto this question who do not have vectorized functions I provide the following proof of concept.

```
#Creating sample data
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(56 * 56), 56, 56))
#Writing an ugly non-vectorized function
logplusone <- function(x) {log(x[1] + 1)}
#example code that achieves the desired result, despite the lack of a vectorized function
df[, 1:56] <- as.data.frame(lapply(df[, 1:56], FUN = function(x) {sapply(x, FUN = logplusone)}))
#Proof that the results are the same using both methods... 
#Note: I used all.equal rather than all so that the values are tested using machine tolerance for mathematical equivalence.  This is probably a non-issue for the current example, but might be relevant with some other testing functions.
#should evaluate to true
all.equal(log(df[, 1:56] + 1),as.data.frame(lapply(df[, 1:56], FUN = function(x) {sapply(x, FUN = logplusone)})))
```

Comment: Note that although it wouldn't work for your particular example - you can get around a function not being vectorized sometimes by running it through the `Vectorize` function.

Comment: Although it would work if you double Vectorized it, e.g. Vectorize(Vectorize(logplusone,"x"),"x")

Comment: ... however, I find the Vectorized functions a little on the difficult to read side, so I prefer the solution presented in my answer simply because it is easier for me (when I go back to the code) to figure out how it is working.

Comment: Really?  I find vectorized code to be much easier to read than sapply code.  For your example code it takes a lot more work to parse what your'e actually doing - "Ok so we want to lapply over the columns of the dataframe... ok, and then we want to use sapply on each of the columns and find the logplus1 value. " compared to "We want to find the logplus1 value of all the observations in the data frame" (which is how I read vectorized code)

Comment: Ah, sorry I wasn't clear.  Vectorized code is certainly easier to read. Code that has been vectorized using the Vectorize function is what I find difficult to work with. To see what is going on inside of it, I have to go back to the original function declaration because I'm not particularly adapt at digging around inside the adhoc environments the Vectorize function makes... and the exposed bit of a function that has been tweaked using Vectorize doesn't make it apparent to me what the original function is.

Comment: If you, like me of the past, find `Vectorize`d functions a pain to look into, take a look at `pryr::unenclose()`.  It helps break open the closure to get a look at the original code.