# How to log(x + 1) a data frame or matrix in R

Tags: r, dataframe, normalization

I am new to coding and am doing some gene expression analysis. I have a very naïve question. I have a a few gene expression data frames with gene names as rows and cell names as columns[Example gene exp. data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMjXX.png). I want to log2 transform the data, but am confused between log and log+1. how do perform log2+1 (log(x + 1)) transformation of a dataframe in R? is it same as log2 transformation? Should I do `t=log(v+1)` ?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apply function to every value in an R dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15215848/apply-function-to-every-value-in-an-r-dataframe)

Comment: From `?log1p`: *"log1p(x) computes log(1+x) accurately also for |x| << 1."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Park's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69535643/8245406) gives the simplest way to log transform a numeric only data.frame but `log(x+1, base = b)` is a different problem.

### `log(x + 1)`

But if the transformation is `y <- log(x + 1)` (could be base 2), then beware of floating-point issues. For very small values of `abs(x)` the results of `log(x + 1, base = b)` are unreliable.

```
x <- seq(.Machine$double.eps, .Machine$double.eps^0.5, length.out = 10)
eq <- log(x + 1) == log1p(x)
eq
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
which(eq)
#[1]  1  4  7 10
```

This is why base R has a function `log1p`. To compute `log(x + 1, base = 2)` or, equivalently, `log2(x + 1)`, use

```
log2p1 <- function(x) log1p(x)/log(2)

eq2 <- log2(x + 1) == log2p1(x)

eq2
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
which(eq2)
#[1]  7 10
```

In both case the difference between `log(x + 1)` and the numerically more accurate version is smaller in absolute value than `.Machine$double.eps`.

```
abs(log(x + 1) - log1p(x)) < .Machine$double.eps
# [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
abs(log2(x + 1) - log2p1(x)) < .Machine$double.eps
# [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Answer (score 3):

for example `dummy` data

```
dummy <- data.frame(
  x = c(1,2,3,4,5),
  y = c(2,3,4,5,6)
)
dummy 
  x y
1 1 2
2 2 3
3 3 4
4 4 5
5 5 6
```

If you want to just `log2` transform data, just use `log(., base = 2)` like

```
log(dummy, base = 2)
         x        y
1 0.000000 1.000000
2 1.000000 1.584963
3 1.584963 2.000000
4 2.000000 2.321928
5 2.321928 2.584963
```

If you want `log2(x+1)` then `log(dummy+1, base = 2)`, or if you want `log2(x)+1` just `log(dummy, base = 2) + 1`

Answer (score 0):

Another solution (adding as a "bonus" a NON numerical column -just in case someone has this problem-) could be:

```
dummy <- data.frame(
     x = c(1,2,3,4,5),
     y = c(2,3,4,5,6),
     text = rep("tt", 5))

str(dummy)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ x   : num  1 2 3 4 5
 $ y   : num  2 3 4 5 6
 $ text: chr  "tt" "tt" "tt" "tt" ...

#save which columns are numeric
idx <- sapply(dummy, is.numeric)

dummy[, idx] <- log2(dummy[, idx] + 1)

str(dummy)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ x   : num  1 1.58 2 2.32 2.58
 $ y   : num  1.58 2 2.32 2.58 2.81
 $ text: chr  "tt" "tt" "tt" "tt" ...
```